# Eliminating duplicate items in an Azure functions workflow?

Tags: azure, binding, duplicates, azure-functions

I have a function app that monitors swappa.com and sends an SMS if there's a phone listing that matches my criteria. A timer trigger function checks swappa every 15 minutes, and a queue trigger function sends a text message for each matching listing. I use bindings exclusively to access storage and twilio to keep things extra "functiony".

What's the best function pattern to maintain state and avoid sending duplicate text messages about the same listings? Even if I can check the age of listings, the price can be lowered on older listings, making them a new match. So I need to track individual listings already processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the two solutions I've come up with so far.

1. Add a queue trigger function in the middle to check table storage. If there's no entry in the table, add the item to both the table and a second queue.

function.json

```
    {
        "disabled": false,
        "bindings": [
            {
                "name": "queueItem",
                "type": "queueTrigger",
                "direction": "in",
                "queueName": "itemqueue",
                "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
            },
            {
                "name": "itemsFoundIn",
                "type": "table",
                "tableName": "itemsFound",
                "partitionKey": "{productId}",
                "rowKey": "{price}",
                "direction": "in",
                "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
            },
            {
                "name": "itemsFoundOut",
                "type": "table",
                "tableName": "itemsFound",
                "partitionKey": "{productId}",
                "rowKey": "{price}",
                "direction": "out",
                "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
            },
            {
                "type": "queue",
                "direction": "out",
                "name": "$return",
                "queueName": "smsqueue",
                "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
            }
        ]
    }
```

index.js

```
    module.exports = function (context, queueItem) {
        if (context.bindings.itemsFoundIn) {
            context.log("queueItem already present in table storage. Treating as duplicate.");
            context.done();
        }
        else {
            context.log("queueItem not found in table storage. Placing in table and destination queue.");
            context.bindings.itemsFoundOut = queueItem;

            context.done(null, queueItem);
        }
    };
```

**Downside**: If this function is disabled for a while and later enabled, there may be parallel executions that check table storage at the same time and pass two instances of the same listing on to the second queue.

2. Use a blob trigger for the sms function instead of a queue trigger. Use blob names to eliminate duplicates. If only bindings are used, a separate queue trigger function probably needs to be added in-between to check for existing blobs, and turn queue items into new blobs.

**Downsides**:

- The blob output binding will update existing blobs, so there's still a chance of parallel executions of the middle function triggering two text messages.
- The sms function could be delayed by 10 minutes according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob.

Comment: In scenario 1 you could set your messages' TTL to < 15 minutes, so the messages from the previous run will be discarded if your function is disabled.

Comment: @Mikhail Great point! Looks like I can use C# and a `CloudQueue` parameter associated with my output binding to queue multiple messages and specify a TTL for them.

Answer (score 1):

If you worry about duplicates, the most straightforward approach will be to keep all the IDs (or hashes) of listings in one state (e.g. in a single table storage row). Load this state in your timer trigger, filter out the parsed results based on that state, then update the state and send out the queue items for SMS.

You should also be able to remove old items from this state to avoid it exploding over time.

I'm not sure how many listings you are going to have. But since you are able to crawl all of them every 15 minutes, I assume my scenario is feasible. Otherwise, use queue-based scenario as described in your answer.

Comment: Ignoring the removal of old items, this was straightforward with javascript and a pair of blob bindings (one in, one out). I had to upload an empty "{ }" json blob initially.